# How can I create a any-type pointer constant in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, constants

I would like to have an integer constant that can be assigned to any pointer. I intend to use this special value to mark recently deleted pointers (just for the debugging purposes). I thought of creating a struct and then overriding the assignment operator= with a template handling every possible LHS pointer and my RHS custom type.

However, afaik there is no way to overload left hand side of assignment operator= except as a member. I came up with this (non-compiling) code, which would produce the intended results if not for the language boundaries.

```
struct TPointerConst
{
    TPointerConst(uint64 InValue) : Value(InValue) { }

    template <typename TPtr>
    friend TPtr& operator=(TPtr& Left, const TPointerConst& Right);
    
private:
    uint64 Value;
};

template <typename TPtr>
TPtr& operator=(TPtr& Left, const TPointerConst& Right) {
    return Left = (TPtr)Right.Value;
}

constexpr TPointerConst DELETED_PTR = 0xFADE404;

/* ... */

int* intPtr = DELETED_PTR;
float* fltPtr = DELETED_PTR;
```

I also thought about casting a value to nullptr_t (which seems really weird when I think about it) just to satisfy the compiler, but as I suspected you cannot cast anything to nullptr_t.

I would like to avoid macros as much as possible, however it wouldn't be too bad if I was left with a single const-like macro for this feature (like good, old NULL). I am targeting at least C++11, so anything going along with modern C++ would be satisfying.

Comment: How about always using `std::unique_ptr` (or shared) then the whole problem goes away  (and `std::vector` for local buffers) ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I intend to use this feature as a debugging tool with my own shared pointers and custom allocators. I actually am trying to abstract the stuff you are talking about from gameplay programmers in my engine, so it's pretty much about implementing those two.

Comment: what you describe very much sounds like `nullptr`

Comment: Are you trying to invent `void *`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template<typename T> operator T*()` will be useful:

```cpp
struct TPointerConst{
    TPointerConst(std::uintptr_t v) :value(v){};

    template<typename T>
    operator T*() const{
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(value);
    }
private:
    std::uintptr_t value;
};



int main(){
    TPointerConst a = 0xCDCDCDCD;
    int* b = a;
}
```

Comment: Yup, I came to the same conclusion few minutes before you posted your solution :) I also decided to make to constructor constexpr so I could have a header-only constexpr to use anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Is the operator T* (with asterisk) going to only get matched when I'm trying to convert to pointer type? That would save me from those static_asserts

Comment: @noisycat yes, the template arguments depend on what type it will be converted to. see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator . and if you want to limit the conversion, using SFINAE instead of `static_assert` will be better.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to handle this issue with overloading conversion operator instead of assignment. Honestly, I thought that those couldn't be template, turns out I was wrong. Here is a proof of concept, to which I am going to add static assertions to make it a bit safer.

```
struct TPointerConst
{
    constexpr TPointerConst(uint64 InValue) noexcept : Value(InValue) { }

    template <typename TPtr>
    constexpr operator TPtr() const { 
        return (TPtr)Value;
    }
    
private:
    uint64 Value;
};

constexpr TPointerConst DELETED_PTR(0x001);

int main()
{
  int* intPtr = DELETED_PTR;
  float* fltPtr = DELETED_PTR;
  
  cout << intPtr << endl << fltPtr;
}
```